# Speech recogition and intonation detection

Tags: ios, core-audio, speech-recognition

I want to make an iOS app to count interrogative sentences. I will look for WH questions and also "will I, am I?" format questions.

I am not very get in the speech or audio technology world, but I did Google and found that there are few speech recognition SDKs. But still no idea how can I detect and graph intonation. Are there any SDKs that support intonation or emotional speech recognition?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no cloud-based Speech Recognition SDK which also gives you intonation. You could search for pitch-tracking solutions and derive intonation from the pitch contour. An opensource one is available in the `librosa` package in Python:

https://librosa.org/librosa/generated/librosa.core.piptrack.html

If you can't embed Python in your application, there is always the option of serving it in a REST API with `Flask` or `fastapi`.